# What is the best way to set empty array for properties in class Java?

Tags: java

I have a class like:

```
public class TemplateFileResponse {
    private String path;
    private List<FileView> children;
}
```

I want to create an instance and set children is empty array. so what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Empty list you mean? Add a constructor

Comment: An array is one thing e.g. `FileView[]`. A `List` is another different thing.

Comment: See Oracle tutorial, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html

Comment: You can create like this private `List<FileView> children = new ArrayList<>();`

Comment: TemplateFileResponse t  = new TemplateFileResponse();
t.setChildren(new ArrayList<>());

Answer (score -1):

You can create an empty list with the `new` operator:

```
public class TemplateFileResponse {
    private String path;
    private List<FileView> children = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You may also want to initialize the `path` field, either in a constructor or inline, because otherwise it will be initialized to `null` by default.

I suggest that you read a tutorial about Java classes, constructors, methods, and instantiating objects to understand how all of this works.

Comment: @Michael I'm not confused. My wording is just poor and incomplete. Presumably inline intialization for `path` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Michael Sure, the `path` field could be left uninitialized at all. But then there would be no point in having it.

Comment: @Michael Feel free to write your own answer or make edit suggestions directly.

Comment: Alright, I have